# Collation To Code Page (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How can I determine which code page a particular collation on SQL Server uses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `COLLATIONPROPERTY` function can be used to get the code page. Here is the code page for every possible collation:

```
SELECT [Name], [Description], [CodePage] = COLLATIONPROPERTY([Name], 'CodePage')
FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
```